# Accessing params of attributes using Beautiful Soup when param =''

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using `BeautifulSoup` to get values for a attribute that is set in html.

Here is the html:

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="white"><input name="period" type="radio" value="3"/></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="white"><input checked="" name="period" type="radio" value="1"/></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="white"><input name="period" type="radio" value="2"/></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="white"><input name="period" type="radio" value="4"/></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="white"><input name="period" type="radio" value="5"/></td>
```

I know to get the value for period (if there was just one) then i could use the following :

```
period = soup.find(name="input", attrs={'name': 'period'})['value']
```

However as there is more than one `period` and I am only interested in the one with the value `checked` specified, I tried this:

```
period = soup.find(name="input", attrs={'checked':'', 'name': 'period'})['value']
```

But as the value of `checked=''` it just defaults to the first `period` it comes across.

How can I fix this

have one more question if I have  and  I want to get the value for period but only for the field where the parameter checked is specified but as checked ="" (i assume thats why) it doesnt work when i set it in attrs any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a similar problem:

You need to change `'checked':''` to `'checked':True`

So it should be:

```
period = soup.find(name="input", attrs={'checked':True, 'name': 'period'})['value']
```